FastAPI on Azure App service via Azure container unable to fetch data from MySQL database
I have created an app using FastAPI to query MySQL database hosted in Azure. I can run the app locally and able to fetch the query data via api all good.
In other words http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and http://127.0.0.1:8000/id/100 works like expected.
Here is my app.
from fastapi import FastAPI
from .db import conn

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
async def read_item():
    return {"message": "Hello there. This is a FastAPI create by ALex.."}

@app.get('/id/{id}')
async def op(id:int):
    cursor = conn().cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"select * from dbo.inventory where id = {id}")
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    return {"id": result[0],
            "name": result[1],
            "q": result[2]}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Running')

When I am hosting this application via Azure App Service and calling the app service URL, I am able to get the default request but not the other request that queries the data from MySQL.
In other words when I hit this url https://xyzwebapp.azurewebsites.net it works but if I try https://xyzwebapp.azurewebsites.net/id/100 it does not work. I get Internal Server Error
I am actually creating a docker image and pushing it to Azure Container Registry.
Here is the docker file
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /API

COPY ./requirements.txt /API/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /API/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /API/app

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]

There are no firewall restrictions to the MySQL server and all the resources are present in the same resource group.
I have tried exposing port 80 in both the docker file and added the in Environmental variables. I have also tried Gunicorn in the docker file like below.
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:80", "main:app", "--worker-class", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker"]

Included the command in the startup settings of the App service
gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app

But, nothing works.
What am I missing? Please give me some insights. Let me know if there are any more info needs to be added.
EDIT
When I ran the app in the Docker and opened the link localhost/id/100 in the browser, I received the same `Internal server error. In the docker Logs found the below error.
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

I have added the below lines in my docker file based on the solution from here but still getting the same error.
Updated docker file
FROM python:3.8.12-alpine

RUN apk update
RUN apk add gcc libc-dev g++ libffi-dev libxml2 unixodbc-dev unixodbc mariadb-dev libstdc++6
RUN apk add bash icu-libs krb5-libs libgcc libintl libssl1.1 libstdc++ zlib curl gnupg

#Download the desired package(s)
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.8.1.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.8.1.1-1_amd64.apk

#(Optional) Verify signature, if 'gpg' is missing install it using 'apk add gnupg':
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/msodbcsql17_17.8.1.1-1_amd64.sig
RUN curl -O https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/4/e/e4e67866-dffd-428c-aac7-8d28ddafb39b/mssql-tools_17.8.1.1-1_amd64.sig

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc  | gpg --import -
RUN gpg --verify msodbcsql17_17.8.1.1-1_amd64.sig msodbcsql17_17.8.1.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN gpg --verify mssql-tools_17.8.1.1-1_amd64.sig mssql-tools_17.8.1.1-1_amd64.apk

#Install the package(s)
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted msodbcsql17_17.8.1.1-1_amd64.apk
RUN apk add --allow-untrusted mssql-tools_17.8.1.1-1_amd64.apk

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /API

COPY ./requirements.txt /API/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /API/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /API/app

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]

Still no luck.
In my local I have installed the ODBC driver to connect with Azure MySQL which is working locally. Something to do with the ODBC driver.
import pyodbc
server = 'somexyzserver.database.windows.net'
database = 'mydatabase'
username = 'xxxxxx'
password = 'xxxxxx'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'


def conn():
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER=tcp:'+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
    return conn


Finally I was able to fix it by installing ODBC drivers in the docker Image. I followed this link and modified my docker file.
FROM python:3.9-slim as python-base
WORKDIR /API
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential \
    curl \
    apt-utils \
    gnupg2 &&\
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt-get update
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list


RUN exit
RUN apt-get update
RUN env ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18

COPY ./requirements.txt /API/requirements.txt

COPY /odbc.ini /API/odbc.ini
RUN odbcinst -i -s -f odbc.ini -l
RUN cat /etc/odbc.ini

EXPOSE 80

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /API/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /API/app

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]

Note: Do not forget to add the odbc.ini file
